# error when i try run my react native app on android studio

Tags: react-native, android-studio

Error Message:

> expo run:android

› Opening emulator ReactTest
› Building app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Jalenoss\kudoshealth\React Native Projects\Temp\Login Screen with backend old app\LoginScreen\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 426
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Calling `[node, C:\Jalenoss\kudoshealth\React Native Projects\Temp\Login Screen with backend old app\LoginScreen\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]` finished with an exception. Error message: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

The current character read is 'i' with an int value of 105
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 0
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
^. Output: info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Error: C:\Jalenoss\kudoshealth\React Native Projects\Temp\Login Screen with backend old app\LoginScreen\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1

I get this error when i try to run and test my react native , I am not sure what the issue is i was trying to fix it for 4 days